# Is there a way to preview what SQL command is actually given out by `execute` and `executemany`?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, mysql-connector-python

In the Python module `sqlite3` and package `mysql-connector-python`, is there a way to preview what SQL command is actually given out by `execute` and `executemany`?

Comment: It's just the first parameter. Please note that parameters are never formatted as strings (which wouldn't be easy for blobs).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13647368/1400554